# Blurry images in gallery

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, photos, samsung-nexus-10

Had a nexus 10 for nearly a year now. Before 5.0 came out w/e version I was on, the extra large images that I had imported from my computer to my nexus would properly resolve and keep their quality when I zoomed in. Now Post-5.0  my large images are just a giant blurry mess.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try going to app info of the gallery app and cleaning data and cache. That will force the app to rescan images again

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean the cache memory and data in app info. One more thing that you should take care of is, have enough free internal memory. If you dont have enough free memory the images wont load.